# How to model available options in a database

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I've been trying to figure out this for a while and I'm getting more and more frustrated because the more I think about it the more confusing it gets.

The question is how to map in a database a relation of available options for a specific row. I came up with this computers example that I think it explains quite well what I'm trying to do

Let's say we want to design a database to store information about computers: what hardware devices are available for an specific computer architecture and also "instances" or products of those computers with a hardware options selected by the user

**Option 1**

[image]

With this approach, nothing prevents a user from selecting hardware for a computer that is not available for that particular architecture

As an example

computer_arch
1, x86
2, x64

hardware
1, 64 bits sound card
2, 32 bits sound car

computer_arch_hardware
(computer_arch_id, hardware_id)
1,2
2,1

Computer instance
serial_number,type,os
1,1,"Windows"

Computer_hardware
1,2 -> Computer of 32 bits assigned a 64bit compatible only hardware

**Option 2**

Another option would be to map the computer_instance_hardware relationship to the computer_arch_hardware

[image]

But with this approach we have redundancy because the "type" of the computer is repeated and, as far as I know this breaks normalization rules

Furthermore, even when there are no wrong linkages between arch and hardware device, you could easily add a x64 device (arch_64, device 64) to a 32 bits computer instance.

**Option 3**

And finally, to ensure the right amount of options is linked with the right architecture, we could replicate the type_id FK to point to both computer_arch_hardware, so all hardware is picked with its assigned architecture, and at the same time with computer_instance so we ensure the architecture_hardware option matchs the type of the computer. But I'm presume this is completely wrong and breaks any single normalization rule for databases

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Option 1: "Nothing prevents the user ...", you can use constraints, triggers etc. if you want to ensure this on database level. Or you have a GUI where only the available options are presented to the user.

Comment: You are getting wrapped around the axle about the concept of arch. The hardware components dictate the arch, in particular the processor sets the rule for the rest of the system's components (not the other way around). A lookup by arch for a computer should be checking just the "processor instance" (you have *types* of processors and *serialized instances* of them as well as whole computers) table which will have both what computer it is in, and by extension the arch. The reason this is confusing right now is you have branches and loops in your schema -- usually a bad thing.